# Is there any way to play custom notification sound in web push notification (Service Worker)?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've looked many resources and but couldn't found positive results. I want to play some sound while receiving a push notification.

```
self.addEventListener("push", (e) => {
  const data = e.data.json();
  // console.log("Push Recieved...");
  self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: data.message,
    icon: data?.icon,
    image: data?.media,
    url: data?.url,
    data: { url: data?.url },
    vibrate: [
      100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 30, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 30, 100, 30, 100, 30,
      100,
    ],
  });
  const playSound = new Audio(
    "https://notificationsounds.com/storage/sounds/file-b8_discreet-song.mp3"
  );
  playSound.play();
  alert("NEW ORDER RECEIVED");
  navigator.vibrate([
    100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 30, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 30, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100,
  ]);
});
```

I tried this way also. But caught an error saying Audio is not a function.

Comment: did u found a solution for it ?

Comment: @rajhim No, it is not supported it seems. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) and checkout this too [link](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/airhorn/issues/18)

Comment: i got temporary solutions, by broadcasting message from  server worker message to the local one here is the link for reference . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API